# AZ CLI (az vm run-command invoke) losing variable data when executed with parameters

Tags: shell, command-line-interface, jq, az

Scenario:

- multiple servers with 1 json file that must have a token replaced
- using jq for json replace
- az vm run-command for running it for all machines
- azuregateways.txt is the list of Azure VMs
- newtokens.csv is the list of new tokens for each gw

The command:

```
for i in `cat azuregateways.txt | awk -F "-00" {'print $1'}`; do newtoken=$(grep $i newtokens.csv | cut -d : -f2); az vm run-command invoke -g $i -n $i-00 --command-id RunShellScript --scripts """cp /home/ops/data/registrationticket.json /home/ops/data/registrationticket.json_old; sudo apt install -y jq; q --arg httpsas "$newtoken" '.OutboxAccessTicket.HttpSas=$httpsas' registrationticket.json_old > registrationticket.json; docker restart mygateway""";done
```

The variable which is being lost is **$newtoken**. The command when executed with --debug:

```
Command arguments: ['vm', 'run-command', 'invoke', '-g', 'ANDROIDGW', '-n', 'ANDROIDGW-00', '--command-id', 'RunShellScript', '--scripts', "cp /home/ops/data/registrationticket.json /home/ops/data/registrationticket.json_old; jq --arg httpsas 'ASDASD ASD ASD ASD ASD' '.OutboxAccessTicket.HttpSas=' /home/ops/data/registrationticket.json_old > /home/ops/data/registrationticket.json", '--debug']
```

So if we can look over the Comnmand arguments section, we notice that AZ CLI is losing the jq variable:

**jq --arg httpsas 'ASDASD ASD ASD ASD ASD' '.OutboxAccessTicket.HttpSas='**

I have tried exporting the variables as global variables, quoting in every possible way, doing a script and running that instead but all behaves the same when I introduce the token as being a variable.

Comment: to clarify, httpsas will take the value of 'ASDASD ASD ASD ASD ASD':
q --arg httpsas 'ASDASD ASD ASD ASD ASD'

This will pass it to key OutboxAccessTicket with sub-key HttpSas but AZ CLI is losing this variable's content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Support has been contacted, they recommended using dictionaries to pass arguments, since after all, az cli runs py in backend:

```
az vm run-command invoke -g $RGROUP -n $RGROUP-00 --command-id RunShellScript  --scripts 'echo "$1" "$2"' --parameters "hello" "'this is just a test'"
{
  "value": [
    {
      "code": "ProvisioningState/succeeded",
      "displayStatus": "Provisioning succeeded",
      "level": "Info",
      "message": "Enable succeeded: \n[stdout]\nhello this is just a test\n\n[stderr]\n",
      "time": null
    }
  ]
}
```